# recursion between two tables

Tags: sql, recursion

Lets say I have this data:

```
create table A (
id int
);

create table B (
id int
);

create table pairs(
id_A int,
id_B int
);

create table owners_A(
owner varchar(1),
id_A int
);

create table owners_B(
owner varchar(1),
id_B int
);

insert into A values (1),(2),(3);

insert into B values(1001),(1002),(1003),(1004),(1005);

insert into pairs values(1,1001),(2,1002),(2,1003),(3,1004),(3,1005);

insert into owners_A values ('A',1),('B',2),('B',3);

insert into owners_B values ('A', 1001), ('A',1002), ('B',1003), ('B', 1004), ('C', 1005);
```

With this structure I'd like to create a query, that starts from a name, finds all A's and B's owned by that name and subsequently also finds all new A's and B's that are paired with already found B's and A's.

So, with the data provided above, if I start from:

- A, I would get 1, 1001, 1002, 2, 1003 (in any order, and can also be
  like (1, NULL), (NULL, 1001), (NULL, 1002), (2, NULL), (NULL, 1003))
- B, I would get 2, 1003, 1004, 1002,  3, 1005
- C, I would get 1005, 3, 1004

I can do it with several queries in a programming language, but is there a way to do it with single sql query?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: using mysql [`WITH RECURSIVE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-examples)

Comment: Which database and which version of it?

Comment: I can choose between several, but let's say its either MySQL or SQLServer. I'm not sure about version numbers, so assume latest version of either.